# Thread safety with shared queues

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I don't have much prior experience with multi-threaded applications in C++, and I'm currently trying to design an application with four threads and three shared queues. This is to be a C++ version of an application I wrote in Python a year ago, but it doesn't run fast enough to meet new requirements (I've always wanted to learn multithreading in C++ anyway, so this seemed like a good opportunity).

The planned threads are:

1) Thread to scrape lines from end of file (equivalent of running tail -f in linux CL)

2) Thread to process lines from file

3) Thread to send processed lines elsewhere

4) Optional thread to write debug output in a logfile (whether or not to use this is specified at runtime)

The queue setup I'm planning to use is:

One shared queue between thread 1 and 2; thread 1 puts items in, thread 2 takes them out. Never the reverse. One shared queue for threads 2 and 3 that behaves the same way as the former. Third optional queue that is written to by all of the first three threads, and read by the fourth thread.

The problem I've encountered is that unlike multiprocessing.Queue() objects in Python, C++ queues aren't thread-safe by default, and I haven't yet found a standard shared queue implementation.

Questions:

1) Can the basic outline I used in Python (above) be re-used in C++ without being a hell of a mess to develop?

2) Is there a standard implementation of a thread-safe queue that I haven't found yet, or will I have to resort to exotic libraries (e.g. Boost) or make my own?

Comment: boost has what you need: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lockfree.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, Have you proved that using separate threads for steps 1, 2, and 3, is any better than using a single thread that performs all three steps in a loop?

Comment: @SolomonSlow In Python, doing all of the steps in a loop in a single thread (which is how I first tried to implement the deisgn) was far too slow for the original requirements. 

Changing to a multi-threaded (technically "multi-processed" in Python due to GIL applying to "threads" there) implementation sped things up to acceptable levels.

Comment: So, if you overlap the input, the output, and the computation, the process can keep up, but if you don't overlap them, it falls behind? That doesn't leave a lot of room between success and failure. If you think that the fire hose from which your program is drinking might flow faster in the future, then it's not to early to start pondering a different, more scaleable architecture, but in the mean time...

Comment: ...I don't know why Gergely Nyiri's answer got voted down. Maybe there's some mistake in it, but at first glance, it appears to be on the right track. Biggest problem with it that I can see (again, at first glance) is that it doesn't provide any back-pressure if the consumer is slower than the producer.  I would put an arbitrary limit on how many items are allowed in the queue, and I would use a second condition variable to block the producer when the queue is full.

Comment: I wouldn't call boost an "exotic" library, its widely used and many of its libraries are finding their way into the c++ standard library

Comment: The consumer will usually be slower than the producer in at least one case (the producer of queue 1 is just getting the tail of a file and dropping lines into the queue with few other actions, while the consumer needs to do a regex check on each incoming line after grabbing it from the queue).

The producer being blocked won't cause any lines to be dropped, will it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use boost, here's a more or less complete implementation:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>

class Queue
{
public:
  Queue() = default;
  ~Queue() = default;

  int pop()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_guard(mutex_);

    while (internal_queue_.empty())
    {
      cond_.wait(lock_guard);
    }

    auto item = i_queue_.front();
    i_queue_.pop();
    return item;
  }

  void push(int item)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_guard(mutex_);
    i_queue_.push(item);
    lock_guard.unlock();
    cond_.notify_one();
  }

private:
  std::queue<int> i_queue_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::condition_variable cond_;
};

int main()
{
  Queue queue;
  queue.push(1);
  auto i = queue.pop();
  return 0;
}
```

Note that pop will block your threads until the queue is empty. Push will notify waiting threads. That is, you only need an loop in your threads to pop the items one-be-one. The loop will be waiting if no more items are ready to consume.

Comment: This should still work if i_queue_ is changed from std::queue<int> to std::queue<std::string>, right?

Second question: The consuming thread and the producing thread for a given queue are meant to operate asynchronously (the producer can drop another item onto the end of the queue while the producer is processing previous items). When you say threads will be blocked, does that mean that they will be fully blocked (unable to do anything at all), or just blocked from accessing the queue?

Comment: @ChrisB yes, `std::string` should work equally well. The queue will block if you try to `pop()` when the queue is empty. If you don't want it to block change `cond_.wait(lock_guard)` to `return` (you'll need to add some sort of flag to say you haven't returned a value)

Comment: the while loop could be replaced with `cond_.wait(lock_guard, [&]{return !internal_queue_.empty();});`, doesn't make a lot of difference in this case but is important when you start to add timeouts.

Comment: It will work with any other types including std::string, of course. Blocking means that if you consume the items from within a loop, the loop will wait if the queue is empty and the blocking will only be released when a new item arrives. This way, you don't need to check in the loop if the queue is empty. As mentioned by Alan above, you can simply remove the usage of condition variable and put this logic in your consumer part. This way, you only need a mutex to make the queue thread-safe.